# iOS - CoreData or Sqlite suite my app?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, join, group-by

My app have 2 entities (or tables).

`Category (id, name)`
`Item (id, name, amount, date, categoryId)`

What I need is

```
SELECT categoryId, Category.name,
    SUM(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = 1, amount, 0)) AS jan
    SUM(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = 2, amount, 0)) AS feb
    SUM(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = 3, amount, 0)) AS mar
    SUM(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = 4, amount, 0)) AS apr
    SUM(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = 5, amount, 0)) AS may
    SUM(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = 6, amount, 0)) AS jun
    SUM(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = 7, amount, 0)) AS jul
    SUM(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = 8, amount, 0)) AS aug
    SUM(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = 9, amount, 0)) AS sep
    SUM(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = 10, amount, 0)) AS oct
    SUM(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = 11, amount, 0)) AS nov
    SUM(IF(MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = 12, amount, 0)) AS dec
FROM Item INNER JOIN Category ON Item.categoryId = Category.id
WHERE YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)) = 2012
GROUP BY categoryId
```

**NOTE: The above query is written in MySQL way, and I'm totally new to CoreData & Sqlite**

In this situation, CoreData **VS** Sqlite, which 1 is more suitable?

How to translate the above sql to CoreData or Sqlite form?

Thanks.

## Edit

Can I mix both? For `CRUD` is using **CoreData**, however for such a complex query use **Sqlite***(FMDB library)*?

By default, CoreData has created a file with extension **.sqlite**. However, in [FMDB github instruction](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb#database-creation) here is with the extension **.db**. Does it matter?

Is the database path `[FMDatabase databaseWithPath:@"/tmp/tmp.db"];` same as CoreData?

Comment: See the documentation for [CASE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case) and [strftime](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: [here](http://rdcworld-iphone.blogspot.in/2013/04/simple-and-basic-coredata-in-iphone.html) is the simple tutorial to get familiar with Core Data, may help you

Comment: @RDC Thanks your comment anyway, but I'm trying to ask about complex query in CoreData which may involve 2 or more table joining

Answer (score 2):

CoreData is not SQL, it does not accept SQL statements. So if you are really tied to using SQL Queries then use SQLite.

Personally I would use CoreData and do my processing in app code, even though I am very familiar with SQL.

CoreData is a "push-up" and will take some time learning it, I would suggest looking for a good book (Marcus Zarra has a second edition of his book just out) and/or some videos.

Comment: is there any example showing how to translate the query above to CoreData?